# Custom Shortcode pulling in Custom Post Type / Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type called 'stories', with categories. there are 5 categories, one of them is 'Fostering'.

I want to pull in all custom 'stories' posts with the category of 'fostering' into a page, I currently have this in my functions.php

```
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'stories', 'stories_function' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

function stories_function($atts) {
    global $wp_query,
        $post;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => ''
    ), $atts );

    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'post_type'         => 'stories',
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( sanitize_title( $atts['cat'] ) )
        ) )
    ) );

    if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

and the shortcode I am using is [stories category="fostering"] but nothing is being pulled in, I have dummy data in this custom post type with the category of 'Fostering' applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code as you missed to pass `cat => Fostering` and make sure `Fostering` is slug of category else pass correct slug of that category

```
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'stories', 'stories_function' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

function stories_function($atts) {
    global $wp_query,
        $post;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => 'fostering'
    ), $atts );

    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'post_type'         => 'stories',
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'story_category',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( sanitize_title( $atts['cat'] ) )
        ) )
    ) );

    if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: I just updated the question with a screenshot of what the categories look like.

Comment: by your screenshot i thing your taxonomy name is wrong its custom post type or default post? please add `taxonomy => your_taxonomy_name` and by seeing your screenshot i thing your taxonomy name is `story_category`